# Getting FileProvider error: "Failed to find configured root that contains"

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-fileprovider

This error appears in several other posts here, but I think that even though I've followed what is in them, I'm still not getting the proper result.

I'm defining the call to getUriFromFile like this in my java class:

```
   File imagePath = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
   Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext().getApplicationContext()),
                packageName+".fileprovider", imagePath);
```

The file is being saved in the folder: /data/data/{packageName}/images

I'm setting the provider like this in my AndroidManifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="{packageName}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Note: {packageName} is literally the name of the package like com.package.packagename, for example.

And finally my provider_paths XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> > /data/data/{packageName}/images

That path is unreachable for FileProvider.

Make it:

```
/data/data/{packageName}/files/images
```

It should be in `getFilesDir()` to begin with.